# Как с помощью Eloquent ORM получить нужную выборку?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

В БД есть 3 таблицы **Книги**, **Категории книг**, **Читатели**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе необходимо получить следующую структуру:

```
Имя читателя
 Категория книг1
  книга1
  книга2
 Категория книг2
  книга3
  книга4
Имя читателя2
 категория1
  книга 1
```

Помогите составить запрос на Eloquent ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При условии что все связи настроены через ORM:

`$readers = Readers::with('books', 'books.categories')->get();

foreach($readers as $reader) {
    echo $reader->name . "\n";
    foreach($reader->books->groupBy('categories') as $category) {
        $flag = true; 
        foreach($category as $book) {
            if ($flag) {
                echo $book->category->name . "\n";
                $flag = false;
            }
            echo $book->name . "\n"; 
        }
    }
}`

Лучшее что пришло в голову, может можно и красивее

Comment: Спасибо. пробовал все варианты остановился на таком. Но мне пришлось связать таблицы readers и books_category (добавить соответствующие поля в таблицы)

Comment: В моем примере реализовано без этой связи, только readers с books, и дальше они группируются сами. Мне кажется такая связь будет неуместной в вашей предметной области, в крайнем случае попробуйте использовать hasManyThrough

Answer (score 1):

Здесь одним запросом не обойтись, вам нужно настроить модели для работы с pivot таблицами и определить отношения между моделями:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Либо в обход Eloquent городить чистый SQL запрос, используя DB::